# Import Certificate to Keystore

Tags: java, ssl

I have generated the keystore using this command :

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias test -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks
```

Under this section i have provided the following response:

```
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  myservice.example.com
```

Now i have generated the certificate with  Common Name:`myservice.example.com`,
How should i import this certificate to my keystore so my client can connect to my service to a specific port and browser shouldn't display the invalid certificate error ?

Comment: The command already saved the certificate into a keystore. (`keystore.jks`). You want your browser to trust it. In order to do that, you need the certificate to be trusted by a Certificate Authority. You can create your own CA but that would only work on your devices as you would need to install the CA certificate on the device. If you want to have a certificate for a domain (or subdomain), the easiest (free) method is likely [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: @dan1st i have generated the certificate from a Certificate Authority with common name `myservice.example.com`  now how should i import this certificate to my existing `keystore.jks`